# How to insert an element into array shifting all others right?

Tags: perl

I have an array, and I want to insert a new element inside it, shifting all other elements to the right:

```
my @a = (2, 5, 4, 8, 1);
# insert 42 into position no. 2
```

Result expected:

```
(2, 5, 42, 4, 8, 1);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
my @a = (2, 5, 4, 8, 1);
splice(@a, 2, 0, 42);   # -> (2, 5, 42, 4, 8, 1)
```

This means: in array @a position 2 remove 0 elements and add the element 42 (there can be more elements added). For more see [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.16.3/functions/splice), specifically this usage:

```
splice ARRAY or EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH,LIST
```

Answer (score 0):

The `unshift()` function in Perl places the given list of elements at the beginning of an array. Thereby shifting all values in the array by right.

```
@a=(1,2,3,4);

print("the output after unshift operation:",unshift(@a,5,6,7,8));
```

O/P: The output after `unshift` operation:

> 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4

Answer (score -1):

It can be easily done by slicing the array in required position.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = (2, 5, 4, 8, 1);
my $pos = 2;
my $val = 42;

say Dumper(\@arr);

@arr = (@arr[0..$pos-1],$val,@arr[$pos..$#arr]);

say Dumper(\@arr);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          2,
          5,
          4,
          8,
          1
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          2,
          5,
          42,
          4,
          8,
          1
        ];
```